# Conditionally start service with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm looking for a way to conditionally start a service with docker-compose. Here is my scenario:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: ecoo-postgres
    image: postgis/postgis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: ecoo_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  smtp4dev:
    container_name: ecoo-smtp
    image: rnwood/smtp4dev:v3
    ports:
      - "3010:80"
      - "2525:25"

  server:
    container_name: ecoo-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./test:/app/test
      - ./prisma:/app/prisma
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - smtp4dev
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: always
```

I'm setting up the environment in my .env file, and want the smpt4dev service to conditionally start based on the ENV variable. Example: If env="dev", start the smpt4dev service, otherwise no.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure your questions are formatted properly; it makes them much easier to read. There is formatting help available in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to conditionally start a service based on an environment variable. You can conditionally start certain services when you run `docker compose up` by making use of [docker compose profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/). For example, if you were to to use a compose file like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgis/postgis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3

  smtp4dev:
    image: docker.io/rnwood/smtp4dev:v3
    profiles:
    - dev

  server:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Then running `docker compose up` would start only postgres and your server, but running `docker compose --profile dev up` would *also* start the `smtp4dev` container.

Alternately, you could arrange for your service to *exit* when the variable is unset. Something like:

```yaml
  smtp4dev:
    image: docker.io/rnwood/smtp4dev:v3
    environment:
      ENV: ${ENV}
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        [ "$ENV" = "DEV" ] || exit 0
        exec "$@"
```

When you run `docker compose up`, the `smtp4dev` container would exit without an error unless `ENV` was equal to `dev`.

In either of the above cases, you would need to remove the dependency between your `server` container and the `smtp4dev` container, since in many cases the `smtp4dev` container will not be running. Your application should gracefully handle an unavailable smtp server.

If you feel that you really need the dependency, you could create two versions of the `server` container using different `profiles`, and only have the dependency when using `--profile dev`.

---

Unrelated to your question, but your existing `depends_on` directive is effectively a no-op. To create the sort of dependencies you want, you need to (a) implement healthchecks for the target service, and then (b) use the extended form of `depends_on` in the dependent service.

Comment: `There is no way to conditionally start a service based on an environment variable.` That's not entirely true, since you can use [`COMPOSE_PROFILES`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/#start-specific-profiles) to select which service profiles to enable ;)

Comment: Sure, but that's just a proxy for the `--profile` command line option. It doesn't permit making something conditional on an arbitrary environment variable.